# How can move camera in google map to marker android

Tags: android, google-maps

I developing application that works on maps.So now I fetch marker from database to map.
I appear only one marker .but camera Do not go to mark shown in the map.

In addition, every time can a new marker appears, its location is different from the previous one. depending on the data stored in the database of Latitude and Longitude.

anyone know solution for that?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    MapFragment mapFragment;
    GoogleMap gMap;
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    CameraPosition cameraPosition;
    LatLng center, latLng;
    String title;


    public static final String ID = "id";
    public static final String TITLE = "nama";
    public static final String LAT = "Latitude";
    public static final String LNG = "Longitude";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        gMap = map;

        getMarkers();



    }
    private void addMarker(LatLng latlng, final String title) {
        markerOptions.position(latlng);
      markerOptions.title(title);
        gMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        gMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


    private void getMarkers() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e("Response: ", response.toString());

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    String getObject = jObj.getString("map");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(getObject);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        //title = jsonObject.getString(TITLE);
                        latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LAT)), Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LNG)));


                        addMarker(latLng, title);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            private void getMarkers() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("Response: ", response.toString());

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                String getObject = jObj.getString("map");
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(getObject);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    //title = jsonObject.getString(TITLE);
                    latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LAT)), Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LNG)));


                    addMarker(latLng, title);

                    //Here you can move the camera to the marker
                      gMap.animateCamera(zoomingLocation(latLng));     
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}


private CameraUpdate zoomingLocation(LatLng latLng) {
    return CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 13);
}
```